# What are the chances of an RSA signature collision?

Tags: rsa

My understanding is: fundamentally it should be hard to produce a different message with the same signature. Therefore chance of collision should be low. But what exactly is the probability of a collision, taking into account stuff like the birthday paradox?

As a consequence, in a system with many signed messages, is it safe to use the (sha-2 or sha-3 hash of the) signature as a unique identifier?

Comment: Are these signatures all made with the same keys, or are there multiple keys?

Comment: @Gilles there are multiple keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you are asking is if we could create $\operatorname{Sign}_S(M_1) = \operatorname{Sign}_S(M_2)$ where $S$ is the private (and secret) key. Obviously, this cannot be the case. If you could then an adversary could claim you signed $M_2$ even though you actually only signed $M_1$. That would also mean that the signature would be repudiable; a signer could simply claim to have signed a different message. Non-repudiability is arguably the most important aspect of a digital signature in the first place (authentication can also be performed using other primitives, e.g. using a static DH key, after all). To round it up: if signatures would collide for separate messages and the same key (and the same configuration parameters) then the algorithm would be fundamentally broken.

Note that many signature generation algorithms are *non-deterministic*. In other words, they take the input of a random number generator as input, and will therefore generate a *different* signature each time the signature is generated. The often used RSA-PKCS#1.5 scheme *is* however deterministic and RSA-PSS can be configured to be deterministic by configuring the salt size to an empty octet string / byte array. Mind you, runtimes may decide not to make the salt size of RSA-PSS configurable, in which case RSA-PSS remains non-deterministic per default.

So yes, you can use a hash to subtract or condense the signature into an identifier, as long as your signature is deterministic (and presuming you want to regenerate the identifier later on). If your hash is too large then you can simply use the leftmost bytes or use a smaller hash function. There are also multiple ways of expanding the result - although that's unlikely required for your use case. Nowadays you would probably use a XOF such as one of the SHAKE functions (part of SHA-3 specs) for expansion. An KDF that supports expansion such as HKDF-expand would also be an option.

---

Note that most if not all modern signatures already include hashing of the data - if just to make sure that the requested property holds. It would be a good idea for the hash functions to have about the same security strength. Of course you need to use a secure hash function (e.g. SHA-2 / SHA-3 and not MD5 or SHA-1) for the hash function.

The smaller the final identifier, the bigger the chance of collisions, of course. Note that you would need $2 \cdot s$ bits to reach a strength of $s$ bits due to the birthday problem. Don't make your identifier too small, especially if you're planning of using many identifiers. Using the full hash output should of course be preferred.

Comment: I think you basically answered my question, but to be sure, I'm wondering if $\text{Sign}_{S_1}(M_1) = \text{Sign}_{S_2}(M_2)$ - the private keys don't have to be the same. It seems for the same reason (non-repudiability) this should be almost impossible, and so it is safe to assume they are unique

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I narrowed it down to make it easier to show that the signatures were necessarily not equal, but in hindsight it is possible to generalize it to separate keys just as well.

Comment: For PKCS#1 v1.5 signature with SHA-1 hash, which is still very common and used to be state of the art, we can now exhibit $M_1\ne M_2$ with $\operatorname{Sign}_S(M_1) = \operatorname{Sign}_S(M_2)$. So there are conditions to _"this cannot be the case"_.

Comment: Yeah, OK, providing that the primitives are secure. If the key size is too small you could run into trouble as well.

Comment: Are you sure that $Sign_{S_1}(M_1) = Sign_{S_2}(M_2)$ is hard to find? Finding this does not lower the security of the system. Because verifying $Sign_{S_2}(M_2)$ with the public key $S_1$ will not work and the other way around. I strongly think your arguments only work for the same key and very much **not** for different keys. At least you need an entirely diffenrent argument

Comment: Agreed. But you can see the modular exponentiation of RSA as a permutation of the hash input. Of course, if you have different permutations then you might get one that maps to the same value for different input. But the chances of that happening are likely astronomically low. You can try and find one pair of input / key combinations that map to the same value, but I think the output is random enough for RSA to make that infeasible as well. However, the question was about a single $S$ if I read correctly, so this is actually a different question (feel free to ask!)